# Should distribution tags always include "-distribution"?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should any tag for a distribution include that *-distribution*, or only when necessary for disambiguation?

For example, the following distribution tags do not include that suffix:

- chi-squared: [chi-squared](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chi-squared) (even though this *is* ambiguous)
- Gaussian (potentially ambiguous; n.b., [gaussian](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaussian) redirects to [normal-distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normal-distribution))
- Weibull: [weibull](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weibull)

But the following do:

- Dirichlet-distribution: [dirichlet-distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dirichlet-distribution) (even though this not ambiguous)
- Pareto-distribution: [pareto-distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pareto-distribution)
- Tweedie-distribution: [tweedie-distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tweedie-distribution) (not ambiguous)

Comment: -1 to indicate disagreement on the basis of @gung's argument, but I've nothing against the question's clarity, research effort, usefulness, stylishness, etc. On those bases it'd be a +1 any day.

Comment: Are you saying you down-voted the _question_ based on disagreement?  What about the question is disagreeable?

Comment: Yep. See gung's answer...

Comment: Obviously I'm relatively new here, but this seems really weird: It's a question for discussion.  I can see disagreeing with an answer, but _disagreeing with a well-formed question because you agreed with an answer to the question_?  Your background suggests some grounding in logic and philosophy: perhaps you could describe the premises or reasoning under which such an action makes sense?

Comment: I understand your question as containing a proposal as a premise for discussion. I don't see a need for the proposal, and I've upvoted answers to this effect. Downvotes on meta-sites (excluding MSE, the big one) are often used differently. In case it's relevant and you weren't aware, they have no ramifications for reputation here (except badges). Pardon any confusion; it's a bizarre policy that had to be explained to me once personally...I've upvoted some questions on MSE that question the policy too, FWIW. Though I've tried to follow it here, I'm not entirely sure it's a good system...

Comment: @feetwet voting works differently in meta to the main site. Here voting indicates agreement/disagreement with a position, not with the quality of the post. It's not personal in any way.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer if there were the usual up and down arrows (to reward post quality, on which badges were based) *and* a second autotallied +/- which indicated agreement/disagreement (when relevant) and which always gave both + and - numbers (+4 means something different on a 54/48 split than on a 4/0 split)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that.  Does Meta have its own intro hidden somewhere?  It sounds like there should be a "Proposal" tag in the mandatory Meta tag set.  E.g., in this case I really didn't have an idea one way or the other, and the title doesn't even incorporate the key nuance in the discussion.  So even re-reading the full question it's not clear what position a voter is taking.  If I had a Proposal it would have had a decisive title like, _Resolved: Distribution tags should only include "-distribution" when necessary for disambiguation._  Now that's a "question" I could see voting on!

Answer (score 6):

I have a preference for shorter tag names when possible.  That is why I created a tag for [rayleigh](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rayleigh), and not `[rayleigh-distribution]` (but I didn't really think about it).

When there are enough questions categorized under a tag, if there is a demonstrated need, we can create additional tags that will further differentiate a category.  As an example, I split up [fisher](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fisher) when it seemed to become problematically heterogeneous (in my mind) and created new tags for [fishersexact](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fishersexact), [fisher-information](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fisher-information), [fisher-transform](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fisher-transform), [ronald-fisher](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ronald-fisher).  I do believe that having the right tags, and having threads tagged appropriately, is very important to the organization and usability of the site.  However, I think think that this will always be a work in progress, requiring some continued maintenance as the site evolves; I don't think it is very possible or useful to try to predict what tags / differentiations will be needed in advance.  For instance, you make a good point about the ambiguity of [chi-squared](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chi-squared), but I haven't noticed an actual problem.  If someone else has, or if one emerges, we could split the tag up.  Until then, I'm inclined to [let it be](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKTyd0qy10o).

Comment: Words of wisdom, mother Mary. +1 for [sneaking in Beatles references](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/92765/32036) (and the other merits of your answer, of course)!

Comment: (+1) It's a pity that we still have [fisher] tag; it currently has 75 questions. All of these 75 threads should really be retagged and the tag eliminated. Do you remember if back then you removed the tag completely (and it re-appeared afterwards) or did you keep it on some threads?

Comment: I didn't remove all of them, @amoeba. Consider [Fisher Distance for feature selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/41574/), it doesn't fit into any of the categories above, it is from Oct 31, '12, & it has never been edited (to add or remove the tag, or for anything else for that matter). The idiosyncratic ones that didn't fit into the categories I came up with, I just left as is.

Comment: I see. Well, currently I would say that if there are idiosyncratic uses of [fisher] tag then it's better to remove any Fisher-related tags from them. As long as [fisher] tag exists, people are going to use it for all sorts of things... Do you think this is worth a separate Meta discussion?

Comment: Nah, we can just start going through the threads & removing the tag, @amoeba.

Comment: OK. I might post something though, perhaps somebody else would join the effort.

Answer (score 4):

Given that we also have a tag for [distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distributions), users can always amend a generic tag like [chi-squared](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chi-squared) in order to avoid ambiguities. For instance, a question concerning the chi-squared test can equally be used together with [inference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inference) to show that the question is not about the distribution. For this kind of tag I think it's beneficial to not have an additional one for the distribution itself. Otherwise we might unnecessarily inflate the number of tags even though existing tags can be used in combination for the same purpose. After all this flexibility is implied by allowing the use of multiple tags per question.