# Ambiguous [fisher] tag should be disambiguated

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-reorganization

We have an ambiguous [fisher](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fisher) tag that says right in the tag excerpt that it's ambiguous and should better be avoided. @gung moved most of the questions out of it [several years ago](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2049/28666), but did not empty it completely so it got lots of new threads in the meantime (75 currently). I think this should still be done.

More specific tags are [fishers-exact](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fishers-exact), [fisher-information](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fisher-information), [fisher-transform](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fisher-transform), [fisher-scoring](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fisher-scoring), [fishers-lsd](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fishers-lsd), and [ronald-fisher](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ronald-fisher) -- all fine tags with clear scopes and excerpts.

**Update:** We now also have the following synonyms:

- [fishers-method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fishers-method)$\to$[combining-p-values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combining-p-values)
- [fishers-discriminant-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fishers-discriminant-analysis)$\to$[discriminant-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discriminant-analysis)

I am posting it here hoping that maybe somebody will want to do this task or join the effort.

Comment: @gung I retagged some Qs about [discriminant-analysis] but it might make sense to create a synonym [fisher-linear-discriminant]->[discriminant-analysis] for the future.

Comment: Similarly, I retagged some Qs to [combining-p-values] but it might make sense to create synonyms [fisher-method] and [stouffer-method] (or fishers- and stouffers-?) pointing to [combining-p-values].

Comment: I've done 6 now of the ones since I last did it (July '13). I'm thinking we should remove the tag from everything, though. It's best for the tag to disappear, this isn't something people are going to be able to use correctly.

Comment: @gung Yes, I agree; that is what I meant.

Comment: @gung What do you think of the synonym suggestions above?

Comment: They're fine w/ me, @amoeba. I don't really know these topics well enough. It seems there were several FLA threads. I don't know FLA vs L / Q DA. Is it worth its own tag? We could also make it a synonym, but maybe there's enough interest on its own.

Comment: @gung Nah, it's the same thing. "FLA" is LDA for two classes. We definitely don't need a separate tag for it (but the synonym would be handy). I have some authority as the highest-rep user [in discriminant-analysis tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/discriminant-analysis/topusers) :-)

Comment: I made a [synonym](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/discriminant-analysis/synonyms).

Comment: Great, thanks. I still think that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method deserves a tag (mapped to [tag:combining-p-values]) as well (see my 2nd comment above).

Comment: There are of course other methods for combining p values which have eponyms so we may be starting down a slippery path if we create tags for any more of  them although I suppose if they are synonyms that does not matter too much.

Comment: @mdewey I think it's a question of what eponyms are popular enough to warrant a tag synonym. This is an empirical question that should be easy to answer using our website: a search for "Fisher's method" yields 77 results, for "Stoufer's method" - 28 results. Anything else with >10 mentions?

Comment: @amoeba, `[fishers-method]` is a synonym [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/combining-p-values/synonyms).

Comment: Are we trying to eliminate the tag? There are four left now for none of which I can find a good replacement.

Comment: @mdewey I did these last four. The tag is gone. Thanks a lot for your help, this was a nice team work. Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: I noticed that a lot of the `[fisher]` questions were about [tag:fishers-lsd], which is legitimate, so I created that & retagged them, @amoeba. I'll post an answer. LSD is mentioned in various threads on CV, but I found 9 that were sufficiently *about* LSD that I added the tag.

Comment: Hmmm, I hadn't noticed the new `[fisher-scoring]` tag. I probably should have put that on some. [This search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=fisher+score+is%3Aquestion+-%5Bfisher-scoring%5D) suggests there are threads that should probably have it.

Comment: @gung It looks like almost all of these threads are not really about Fisher's scoring. I noticed one that clearly *is* and put the tag on it now, but overall I don't think we are missing a lot of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Years ago I reorganized the `[fisher]` tag.  I created several new tags (e.g., `[f-e]`, `[f-i]`, `[f-t]`, and `[r-f]`).  But I left the tag on ~25 threads that seemed to merit some connection to "fisher", but where idiosyncratic.  I edited the excerpt to put a rather specific message that the tag should only rarely be used, and the other tags should be preferred.  I think now that that strategy is unworkable and was a mistake.  Not surprisingly, perhaps, many people over the intervening years ignored that usage guidance, necessitating this thread.

Over the past couple days, @mdewey, @amoeba (thanks, guys), and I have cleaned up the remaining `[fisher]` tagged threads.  In doing so, we have created [fisher-scoring](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fisher-scoring) and [fishers-lsd](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fishers-lsd).  I also created two synonyms (noted in the body of the question above).  After 24 hours, `[fisher]` should disappear.  Let us hope it won't be recreated.